# Script not running at startup

Tags: scripts, startup

I'm an Ubuntu 13.04 user and I'm trying to run a script at startup. I created it in `/etc/init.d/`, gave it `chmod 755` and ran the `update-rc.d <your script> defaults` command. The script is remapping my mouse's keybindings and contains the following:

```
#! /bin/sh
xinput set-button-map 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 8
```

It runs correctly if I do it manually, but I want it to run with startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't that run it before there's an X Server around for it to interface with?

The simplest way to get this to work would just be to add `sh -c "xinput set-button-map 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 8"` to your start-up applications and that'll run it when you log in.

There's also `/etc/xdg/autostart` for all users, into which you can write .desktop files (look at the existing ones for syntax help).

Answer (score 1):

If you add scripts to the `rc.d` it will start before the Xserver or xorg is up, also it will apply from the `root` user perspective. The most preferable place to do this is `/etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/` for system wide X start up scripts or `~/.xinputrc` for users based ones.

For this you should install `im-config` (it should be the default in Ubuntu) and add your script in that folder or file.